# Too many arguments to method call

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, compiler-errors, arguments

I am trying to set the initial text for what the twitter message should say in my app using a NSString from my appDelegate. Check out the code here:

```
    NSString *tweet;
tweet=[MyWebFunction tweet:appDelegate.stadium_id];


if([deviceType hasPrefix:@"5."]){

    // Create the view controller
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [twitter setInitialText:@"@%",tweet];
```

The problem is, is there is an error at the twitter setInitialText that there are Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2. ?!?!?

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TWTweetComposeViewController` method `setInitialText` only takes one argument, being of type `NSString*`. You cannot simply format any and all `NSString` variables passed to a method as you can with the `NSString` method `stringWithFormat` (which is, I imagine, where you've seen the syntax `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myString]`).

In your case, you either need to simply call:

```
[twitter setInitialText:tweet];
```

or call:

```
[twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet]]
```

**EDIT**
I feel it necessary to add, to further your understanding, that a method only takes a variable number of arguments (such as `stringWithFormat`) when its declaration ends with `...`

For example, looking in the docs for `NSString` reveals that `stringWithFormat` is declared as such:

```
+(id) stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;
```

Similarly, `arrayWithObjects` in `NSArray` is declared as such:

```
+(id) arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...;
```

which one would use like:

```
NSString* myString1 = @"foo";
NSString* myString2 = @"bar";
NSNumber* myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myString1, myString2, myNumber, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[twitter setInitialText:tweet];`

If you really need formatted text for a more complex case, try

`[twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet]];`

Answer (score 0):

```
"[twitter setInitialText:@"@%",tweet];"
```

you just got your "@" and your "%" the wrong way round it should be

```
[twitter setInitialText:@"**%@**",tweet];
```