# Too many argument calls to method

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

In xCode when i debug using `po` i get this error.

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",item.CNUMBER]
error: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2
```

Some questions that i looked at but doesnt help me.

[Too many arguments to method call expected 1, have 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838243/too-many-arguments-to-method-call-expected-1-have-2)

[Too many arguments to method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405837/too-many-arguments-to-method-call?rq=1)

[Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2?(Xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812984/too-many-arguments-to-method-call-expected-1-have-2xcode?rq=1)

I even had a moment where i questioned my sanity and went to apples documentions. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long %C dash", 0x2014]; // from apples doc
```

and the results are the same...

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long %C dash", 0x2014];
error: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2
```

im using macOS 10.12.4 and xCode 8.3.2. I even reinstalled xCode from scratch. Any ideas what can be causing this!?

e: using `po item.CNUMBER` gives me the phone number like its supposed to

`item` is just a model i use to parse a json response, no methods involved.

```
LeasesModel *item; // declared as an instance var
```

...

```
@interface LeasesModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *ID, *PROPERTYNAME, *ADDRESS1, *ADDRESS2, *CITY, *STATE, *ZIP, *WBPOINT, *COMMENTS, *CNAME, *CNUMBER, *CEMAIL, *CCOMPANY, *ISRETAILSPACE, *ISOFFICESPACE, *ISCOMMUNITYFACILITY, *SQFT, *STATUS, *ASKINGRENT, *FLOORCOUNT, *FLOOR1SF, *FLOOR1ASKING, *FLOOR2SF, *FLOOR2ASKING, *FLOOR3SF, *FLOOR3ASKING, *FLOOR4SF, *FLOOR4ASKING, *FLOOR5SF, *FLOOR5ASKING;
@end
```

e: i was unable to reproduce the error in a new project.

Comment: The same test works fine for me in my Xcode console.  The only difference between mine and yours is I don't have your `item` object, and don't know anything about the `CNUMBER` method.  Can you post item.h and the definition of CNUMBER.

Comment: @danh - Did you try the second ("from apples doc") example? That worked for me (as did examples using variables) but I using a different macOS/xCode at the time so could not conclude anything definitive.

Comment: @CRD, yes, just tired and that worked for me as well.  I'm close enough on macOS (10.3), and on Xcode 8.3.2.  The OP must have something in the project that's polluting the behavior (maybe an unnoticed NSString extension)

Comment: If I pause my app with the pause button, I get the same error. After I pause once on a breakpoint, it works fine.

Comment: @Willeke i get the error when hitting a breakpoint, i rarely ever use the pause button.

Comment: @danh i added the item object to the question, its just a model class for a json response. `CNUMBER` is short for `ContactNumber`

Comment: @Sara, can you reproduce this on a new, empty project?

Comment: @danh using the apple docs example, i was unable to reproduce the error in a new project. hopefully that means its a project settings, i just wouldnt know where to look tbh.

Comment: @Sara, I'd get that important fact into your question. Search the offending project for NSString extensions (or even a subclass).

Comment: wow, it was an extension that was causing that error. And i was gonna go mess around in build settings. thanks @danh

Comment: @danh if you dont mind me asking, what led you to think it was an extension? That would have been the last place i thought of

Comment: @Sara, it's code that should obviously work.  We know NSString isn't buggy, so the next thought is: maybe we're not running the code we think we're running. Macro's are a good candidate -- and thinking was encouraged by your choice of all caps on the property name.  (That's why I asked to see the object definition).  Extension was next on my list, and subclass was last.

Comment: @danh Why do I get the error in a new unmodified project?

Comment: @Willeke, I don't know. Are you sure it isn't  modified somehow, maybe via a template?

Comment: @danh No, I do Create New Xcode Project, run, pause, po. I didn't modify any templates. Maybe something isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @danh, we figured out the issue with was a NSString extension method. Removing it allowed me to debug like normal.